# Dynamically naming the file name ( Excel File ) in C#

Tags: c#

I want to name the file dynamically in C#.

i.e) Name of the File will be picked from Database. When i generate the Excel File and save in a working folder, the file name should be picked from the variable !!

i am searching online to find the solution !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably when you generate the file, one of the method calls (e.g. `SaveAs`) takes the name of the file as a parameter. So just don't hard-code that argument... use the value fetched from the database instead.

If that isn't enough information, please clarify your question.

Comment: Actually, i am generating the Excel File through SSIS Package .. and values are passed through parameters .. pkgTR.Variables["sPath"].Value = @"c:\TransactionReport.xls";  At present, i am passing the syntax as mentioned above ..! Instead of TransactionReport.xls .. i need to keep a dynamic name !!

Comment: @Chok: So set the `Value` property using the value read from the database instead. I don't see what the difficult bit is...

Comment: No i want the syntax something like this .. @"c:\ '+ sFileName +' ";

Comment: @Chok: Well apart from the quotes, you're there... `pkgTR.Variables["sPath"].Value = @"c:\" + sFileName;` - I'm not sure why you're trying to use single quotes though...

Comment: @Chok: It's not a "trick" - it's pretty basic C#. To be honest, if this sort of thing is causing you problems, you'd be well advised to put down Excel interoperability for the moment and practise on some simple C# development (writing test console apps) in order to become more familiar with the language. Then when you're confident in the basics, you can move on to trickier things.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
string sFileName = "ExcelFile";
FileStream  fExcel =  new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + sFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: Actually, i am generating the Excel File through SSIS Package .. and values are passed through parameters .. pkgTR.Variables["sPath"].Value = @"c:\TransactionReport.xls";  At present, i am passing the syntax as mentioned above ..! Instead of TransactionReport.xls .. i need to keep a dynamic name !!